# SQL Server full text search - why apostrophe filters results despite wildcard?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, apostrophe

I am experiencing issue with the full text search in SQL Server.

On my local server (SQL Server 2008) the following query returns the expected row number : 1305

```
select count(*) 
from EditionSearch 
where contains(title, '"*actualité*"')
```

Most of the results come from a common title, containg an apostrophe:

```
l'actualité
```

On the production server (SQL Server 2014 on Azure), I get 131 results. The query skips all titles containing the word prefix by an apostrophe, and take *only the ones without prefix.*

Seems that the wildcard doesn't works with the apostrophe (considered as a word breaker maybe?) :'(

Both full text catalog have been created with the same queries, without accent sensitivity.

The differences: SQL Server versions, and full text languages installed (both automatically installed).

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fulltext_languages;
```

Returns 53 languages on SQL Server 2014, and 48 on SQL Server 2008.

SQL Server 2014 added

```
1055    Turkish
1045    Polish
1044    Bokmål
1032    Greek
1030    Danish
1029    Czech
```

Can this issue come from installed languages?

Thanks a lot in advance